# How to identify input and output elements in React JS?

Tags: reactjs

I have Here React JS Code. with 2 input areas. and 2 output areas. How to link 1 to 1 and 2nd to 2nd.

```
class MarkdownEditor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.md = new Remarkable();
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = { value: 'Hello, **world**!' };
    this.md2 = new Remarkable();
    this.handleChange2 = this.handleChange2.bind(this);
    this.state2 = { value: 'Hello, **Brad Pitt**!' };
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  }
  handleChange2(e) {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  }

  getRawMarkup() {
    return { __html: this.md.render(this.state.value) };
  }
  getRawMarkup2() {
    return { __html: this.md2.render(this.state2.value) };
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="MarkdownEditor">
        <h3>Input</h3>
        <label htmlFor="markdown-content">
          Enter some markdown
        </label>
        <textarea
          id="markdown-content"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          defaultValue={this.state.value}
        />
        <textarea id="markdown-content2"
          onChange={this.handleChange2}
          defaultValue={this.state2.value2}
        />
        <h3>Output</h3>
        <div
          className="content"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.getRawMarkup()}
        />
     <div
          className="content"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.getRawMarkup2()}
        />


      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<MarkdownEditor />,
  document.getElementById('markdown-example')
);
```

Is it "Value" that can be changed or "state"? Here only Text area input is used but I do want to use other inputs such as radio, numbers and checkboxes. Moreover Where do I perfrom Arithmatic calculations in code above

Answer (score 1):

You can only use one `this.state` in your component. It's a javascript object so you can have your two keys inside it:

```
this.state = { input1: "", input2: "" }
```

Then, to update the values, you can call `this.setState` for each key:

```
handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ input1: e.target.value });
}

handleChange2(e) {
    this.setState({ input2: e.target.value });
}
```

`this.setState` will update the state by merging the previous state with the object you send him (`{input1: e.target.value}`) that will cause a rerender of you component with the updated value.

Now in your `<textearea>`, you must use **"value"** instead of **"defaultValue"** and read the value directly from the state i.e. `{this.state.input1}` for the former and `{this.state.input2}` for the latter.

This is what we call a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) in React.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input value = {this.state.formValue}>
```

And you can get or set input's value in other functions of component